# MySQL, indexes and "Lock wait timeout exceeded"

Tags: mysql, indexing

Today I have been working on some MySQL performance issues. I used EXPLAIN to find table scans and fixed some issues by creating indexes.

My reads because super fast.

But ever since, update queries are very problematic. When I restart Mysql, the first few inserts or updates work fine. After that, update queries start showing the error "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" after 60 seconds.

Is Mysql recreated large indexes on every insert/update? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MySQL recreates indexes on every update.  You need to find the sweet spot.  Only put indexes on keys that will be used on `WHERE` conditions (or join `ON` conditions).

If you index everything, your updates will be too slow.  If you index nothing, your reads will be too slow.

If you still have performance issues after narrowing your indexes down to exactly what you need, you should probably re-evaluate your data structure.

Comment: I did exacly what you say. I created indexes only on columns that are in where clauses or ON conditions, after EXPAIN pointed out that the table was scanning rows.

Comment: Okay, we'll need to see more information about your table structure to help further.